# ui tab select using variable

Tags: user-interface, jquery-ui-tabs

I am having problems when trying to change a tab

The code below is working

```
$('#tabs').tabs('select', 1);
```

WORKING FINE

The code below

```
var nextTab=$('#nextTab').val();
$('#tabs').tabs('select', nextTab);
```

IS NOT WORKING

The nextTab variable is a valid tab index

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure nextTab holds a valid tab index? If yes, don't know if this makes a difference, but try converting it to a Number:

```
var nextTab = Number($('#nextTab').val());
```